# Goober Issue From 'react-hot-toast'

Tags: reactjs, expo

I got the error when trying to build my expo app to native app, here's the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwRpg.png)

Here's my version of react-hot-toast

```
"react-hot-toast": "^2.3.0",
```

Comment: I googled for "react-hot-toast react native goober" and found this issue. https://github.com/timolins/react-hot-toast/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue when I tried to use react-hot-toast with expo.
Maybe you need to define a custom toast component using useToaster() when using toast in React Native like the example below.

https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/use-toaster

> Usage with React Native
> Headless mode is perfectly suited to add notifications to your React Native app. You can check out this example.